# How to make justified alignment in open office writer with normal distance between words?

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

i want to write a 2 column paper for the university and the standard template is using  justified  alignment  like this :

> My document My document My document My document My do-
>   cument My document My document My document My docume-
>   nt My document My document My document.

you know ... but when i choose justified  alignment instead of left alignment, the words get unusual distance to get justified per lines...

what's my mistake ? i have to use an special option or template to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Ted, that extra space is what makes it possible to justify.  Open Office isn't real smart about it, but most word processors aren't any smarter.  If you really need it to look slick, you should look at teX and LaTeX, which use an optimal scheme.

Failing that, you can try twiddling hypenation and what's called "kerning".  Just look for "kerning" in the help.